# WifiInfo SSID null directly after WIFI_STATE_ENABLED received

Tags: android, android-intent, android-wifi

When WIFI_STATE_ENABLED is received by my BroadcastReceiver directly after that the SSID value of WifiInfo is null. However it works when I add a Thread.Sleep() for 800 milliseconds. There seems to be a delay in the event connecting the wifi and the WifiInfo object actually getting the information. The snippet below works:

```
    else if (intent.getAction().equals(WifiManager.WIFI_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION)) {
        int extraWifiState = intent.getIntExtra(WifiManager.EXTRA_WIFI_STATE, WifiManager.WIFI_STATE_UNKNOWN);
        switch (extraWifiState) {
        case WifiManager.WIFI_STATE_ENABLED:
            // The SSID is null just after connection is established. This
            // event seems over eager.
            try {
                Thread.sleep(800, 0);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            if (!wifiFunctions.connectedToGConnectHotspot()) {
                removeConnectedNotification();
            } else {
                settings.setLastNotificationTime(System.currentTimeMillis());
                notifyUserOfAvailableHotspot(true);
                return;
            }
            break;
```

That works but it is extremely dodgy. What if it takes longer on some devices? Is there another way to get the connected SSID. I looked and EXTRA_NETWORK_INFO but it is deprecated as of API level 14 and also does not seem to include the SSID anyway. Is there another method to get the SSID without introducing an artificial wait?

Comment: Code in your Manifest file???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`WIFI_STATE_ENABLED` is not the action you want to capture if you're looking to get the SSID. The one you might be more interested is [NETWORK_STATE_CHANGED](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.html#NETWORK_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION).

The WIFI_STATE_ENABLED occurs when the WiFi device on the phone is switched on - it's not necessarily connected anywhere at that point.

Edit: as pointed out in the comments, NETWORK_STATE_CHANGED triggers on many other events too. For strictly monitoring connection to WiFi access point, [SUPPLICANT_CONNECTION_CHANGE_ACTION](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.html#SUPPLICANT_CONNECTION_CHANGE_ACTION) is the correct action to listen.

Comment: That makes perfect sense, but I can't get that event to work. SUPPLICANT_CONNECTION_CHANGE_ACTION seemed to do the trick though. NETWORK_STATE_CHANGED based on its documentation triggers during other times too, like when switches between wifi and 3g happen. I am not really interested in those.

Comment: If you change your answer to SUPPLICANT change I will accept it. :)

Answer (score 1):

I have been using SUPPLICANT_CONNECTION_CHANGE_ACTION for an app I'm working on and found it works great when the Wifi is enabled and then connects.

The problem is that it never seems to be triggered when changing Wifi networks while Wifi stays enabled.  The only action that seems to occur in this case is  NETWORK_STATE_CHANGED (3 times, with the first 2 having WifiInfo as null).

I have only tried 1 device (Galaxy S3 4.1) so I don't know how widespread this is but it seems SUPPLICANT_CONNECTION_CHANGE_ACTION should work for this.  The other caveat is I'm switching between 2 SSIDs on the same access point (2.4 and 5.2) so maybe Android is not actually considering it to be a network change.

EDIT: Tested with Touchpad running CyanogenMod 10 using Galaxy S3 as a second Wifi Hotspot. SUPPLICANT_CONNECTION_CHANGE_ACTION does NOT trigger when switching SSIDs (and access points) while Wifi stays enabled.  The event only seems to occur when connection is made as a result of enabling Wifi.  This actually seems like a bug - I have an old Android 2.2 Legend lying around so I will try that as well.  Unfortunately none of this is testable on virtual devices.